# Error: Symbol 'iac' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type; did you mean 'nac'?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

i have an error in this thing but I don't know why it detected it as no implicit type. In the compiler it says `Error: Symbol 'iac' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type; did you mean 'nac'?`

but I already declared it like this

```
PROGRAM SUSPAP
! Analysis of Suspension Bridge Structures

IMPLICIT NONE

CHARACTER NJO*70, NCA*70, NAL*70, NDL*70, NAQ*70, NLL*70, NNL*70, NAC*70

REAL*8  ACCE (4000) ,COR (2000) ,DIN (4000) ,DIS (2000) ,DISE (4000) , &
        DISEX (200) ,DISP (4000) ,DIST (2500) ,DIS1 (2000) ,DIS2 (2500) , &
        EFO (14000) ,EFOT (1400) ,ELD(500) ,ELT(500) ,EMOD (1000) , &
        EQFO (14000) ,EQFOT (14000) ,EQLO (2000) ,FORC(2000) ,GDI (2000) , &
        GLO(2000) ,GLOD(100) ,GLOL(100) ,OPR (10000) ,OPS (10000) , &
        PEFF (2000) ,PEQI (2000) ,PEQS (1000) ,PEQT (2000) ,POIS (1000) , &
        PRO(5000) ,ROT (1000) ,SMEG (1000) ,SMEL (1000) ,SMG4 (1000) , &
        STEF (70000) ,STEG (1000) ,STG(70000) ,STEL(1000) , &
        STG4 (1000) ,STRE(1000) ,STMM (70000) ,STMS (10000) , &
        SMMM (70000) ,SMMS (10000) ,VELO(4000) ,WTY (1000) , &
        ACC (4000) ,VEL (4000) ,DAT1 ,DAT2

INTEGER I, LI

DIMENSION   IAC (4000) ,IDE(2, 500) ,INC (2000) ,LISEX (400) ,LTY(1000) , &
            LPOIN (2000) ,MBEL (500) ,MPRI (1000) ,NDON (5, 50) ,NIST (5000) , &
            NLOD (10) ,NMAS (5000) ,NNEL (1000) ,NPRI (1000) ,NTY(1000)

DATA NDI/3/ ,NOE/4/ ,NDN/6/ ,NDE/24/ ,NODEL/10/
```

Comment: btw i'm using .F90 on the file name, and i was compiling it with gfortran. And then the problem arise is like that

Comment: You specified `iac` having a dimension / size, but not a type (`integer`). Due to the `IMPLICIT NONE` which  is very good to use (I would say mandatory) this shows (now).

Comment: hi, thanks for the responds. I still not quite get why the compiler not recognized it. Anyway, how u guys declared dimensions, i mean, did i declared it in the wrong way?

Comment: You declared the *dimension* of `iac` just fine (if a little retro). You just didn't declare its *type*.

Answer (score 0):

The `dimension` statement declares that something has (or several somethings have) the DIMENSION attribute.  Like other attribute specifications statements, such as `allocatable`, `parameter` and `save`, the `dimension` statement does not specify a *type* of an entity.

With `implicit none` in effect you must explicitly declare the type of all local variables and the way to do that here is to use a type declaration statement:

```
real*8 iac ! A non-standard type declaration statement
dimension iac(4000)
```

(You should avoid using `real*8` and instead chose a type declaration that is understood by all Fortran compilers.)

It's possible to specify both the type of an entity and its attributes in a single statement

```
real*8, dimension(4000) :: iac ! A non-standard type declaration statement
```

or to specify the type and attribute(s) separately

```
real*8 iac ! Still non-standard
dimension iac(4000)
```

but an explicit type declaration is required to avoid implicit typing.